# Regex match between double square brackets ignoring newline. It's possible?

Tags: regex, filebeat

I started to use kibana and I send log files using Filebeat.
I got the following problem:

My ( Error ) logs are like this  :

[Error] ...

**[[** Stack trace line 1 : [...] ( \n )

Stack trace line 2 : [...] ( \n )

Stack trace line 3 : [...] ( \n )

Stack trace line 4 : [...] ( \n )

.....

Stack trace line 50 : [...] **]]**( \n )

I want to use a regex that will return only what is between "[[" and "]]" and I can't do that because of the newlines.

This *regex* is used in filebeat.yml (filebeat configuration file).

Is there a way to skip or escape that (newline) ?

My currently regex looks like this : (\[\[)(.*)(.|\n?)(\]\])

Comment: Try specifying the following options in the *filebeat.inputs* section of the *filebeat.yml* config file: `multiline.pattern: '^\[{2}'`, `multiline.negate: true`,
`multiline.match: after`, `multiline.flush_pattern: '\]{2}$'`

Comment: I tried this pattern, but it groups more lines that it should. For example :                        If I got 2 lines that should group  [[ line1 ... line 2 ]], than followed by other lines that should not group, it still groups. My kibana log will look like this -> { [[ line 1... line 2 ]] [[ line 3 line 4]] ... }

Comment: It looks as though the `flush_pattern` is not found. Are those `]]` at the end of the line? Try removing `$` to check if it works better.

Comment: The brackets **]]** are at the end of the line for sure. I removed **$** and tried. Still bad output. I tried with **flush_pattern: '\]\]'** a lot and didn`t worked. Now I modified the output of the log and for the momment I log only lines that contain a given string, like 'stdout' ( using **include_lines: ['.*stdout.*']** in filebeat.yml).